# SharePoint solution for spreadsheet daily planners

Tags: calendar, spreadsheet

Does anybody have a good idea for using SharePoint (probably calendars) instead of creating what I call 'daily planner' spreadsheets like in the screenshot I've attached below. Personally I've never been able to present a solution to an end user that they actually prefer. Typically these spreadsheets will include one worbook for each month and show what each team member is doing on a particular day. It's colour coded into categories and also allows notes. The attraction to these spreadsheets is the data input simplicity, which is normally a copy and paste once an entry of a given category exists which is first entered by selecting some cells, select a background colour and type into the (and/or) first cell / notes column. Also these spreadsheets provide end users an easy visual cue as to who is doing what on a given day.

I have tried using a SharePoint calendar, creating some columns, setting up views and enabling colour-coding based on a category column but end users prefer these spreadsheets because it gives them an easier view of what is happening on a given day and the data input takes longer.

I would like to utilise SharePoint functionality to deliver benefits such as Outlook calendar integration and concurrent editing abilities, but so far these benefits aren't enough to tempt my end users into new ways of working.

Has anybody had any success in using SharePoint for this type of 'daily planner' functionality?

Regards,

[image: Example 'daily planner' spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can be done; One advice (*actually it is a Steve Jobs quote*):

> start with the End User Interface and built back towards technology.

Your challenge will be how to replicate the (fancy) Excel day/duration calculations in SP.

If you are on 2013 you might want to dig through the [Apps in the Store](http://store.office.com) to see what has been built (and how) by others.

If you don't master them yet you might need to learn SP technologies:

- Workflows
- CSR - Client Side Rendering (for fancy colors and better UX)

My advice: don't try to built an end-product, built a POC (Proof of Concept) exploring the UI/UX and technologies needed.

Then **start over, and do it right**